# Cannot decrypt on boot, keyboard not detected

Tags: boot, keyboard, decryption

I just freshly installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 but I can't decrypt my hard drive because my keyboard does nothing at the decrypt screen after Grub. Keyboard works fine on Grub though. Despite having it plugged into the ps/2 port it still doesn't work, neither do my USB 2.0 or 3.0 ports.

My understanding is that the keyboard depends on drivers that are not loaded until I decrypt the hard drive, because the drivers are contained within the OS?

When I attempt to load up in the 3.16.0-23-generic kernel the PC freezes. I am able to load after I select the 3.16.0-33-generic kernel (recovery), after I decrypt through recovery mode I can select resume.

How do I fix my PC so that the keyboard is recognized when I get to the decrypt screen so I can load up normally?

Motherboard: Gigabyte Z97X-SLI (Rev 1.0)
Keyboard: Cooler Master Quickfire Stealth

Comment: Update: Tried simply unplugging and plugging it back in again, my keyboard caps lock turns on for a second and then turns off. Still unable to type anything though.

Comment: Also, I have my OS installed on an SSD and seem to be having a similar issue to this user: http://askubuntu.com/questions/322019/encrypted-ubuntu-13-04-on-ssd-does-not-work?rq=1

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584197/double-different-key-press-detected) yet?